# Get last row of specified range in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

How do I get the last row of a range that has already been specified and defined and is known to contain the data I want? It seems to me this should be a property of some sort like `Range.Row` but [Range.Row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.row) gives the **first** row number in the range and I want the ***last*** row number.

Now the problem is my range doesn't begin in row 1 of the source sheet - it actually begins in row 3 and goes through row 756. Below is the address of my range as viewed by the debugger and it is defined correctly. But since it begins at row 3 using `Rows.Count` will not work, since it results in 754 instead of 756.

`Rows.Count` is a reference to the range which is a subset of the original sheet. I want the row number of the last row from the original spreadsheet, exactly as it is in the address below. In other words is there some property on Address that will give me the 756?

```
transData = transactionsDataRange.Address

: transData : "$A$3:$AP$756" : Variant/String
```

The address presented in the debugger is correct. All that I want is to extract the row value of the lower right cell in the specified range which would be 756. I can parse the address value and will do that if necessary, but I'm wondering if Excel VBA has a simpler way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative approach

```
Sub x()

Dim transactionsDataRange As Range

Set transactionsDataRange = Range("$A$3:$AP$756")

MsgBox transactionsDataRange.Rows(transactionsDataRange.Rows.Count).Row

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, but Scott's does work.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Dim LstRow as Long
LstRow = transactionsDataRange.Row + transactionsDataRange.Rows.Count - 1
```

[image]

Comment: This will only work if my specified range begins in row 1 of my worksheet. Range is a subset of the worksheet and can begin anywhere. I have a worksheet with 756 rows only 754 of which are relevant. But I want to refer to the last row in the original worksheet which could be Count + or - some unknown amount.

Comment: @Nelda.techspiress: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @Nelda.techspiress no, it will work with what ever row it is on.  in your example `transactionsDataRange.Row` will return `3` and `transactionsDataRange.Rows.Count` will return `754` or the number of rows in the range so the math is `3+754-1` which is `756`

Comment: @Nelda.techspiress have you tried the exact formula I gave.  It will return 756 as it adds the start row of the range to the row count and subtracts `1` it will work no matter where the range starts.

Comment: Yes, this worked after I typed it in correctly. But I was looking for a property that explicitly worked with the given range without any calculation being performed, which is why I accepted SJR's answer.

Comment: @Nelda.techspiress I have no problem with you choosing the other answer, just wanted to ensure that you saw that this worked.  I would have chosen the other also.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TestMe()        
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Worksheets(1).Range("D10:D15")
    Debug.Print myRange.Rows.Count + myRange.Row - 1        
End Sub
```

It prints 15. `myRange.Rows.Count` is 6 and `myRange.Row` is 10. Or if you like 1-line-functions, this could be ok:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print LastRowOfRange(Range("D15:E199"))
End Sub

Function LastRowOfRange(myRange) As Long
    LastRowOfRange = myRange.Rows.Count + myRange.Row - 1
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifies the last cell in the range.

```
Sub test()
    Dim transactionsDataRange As Range
    Dim rngT As Range

    Set transactionsDataRange = Range("$A$3:$AP$756")
    With transactionsDataRange
        Set rngT = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
    End With
    MsgBox rngT.Row
End Sub
```